# How can I show stars in yii cstarrating extension?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

Hey I am working on cstarraing extension of yii. I am using the following code to show the stars from database :

```
   $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $count=Reviews::model()->count($criteria);
        $pages=new CPagination($count);
        $criteria->order="time DESC";
        $criteria->condition="user_id=".$_GET['user_id']." AND status='approve'";
        // results per page
        $pages->pageSize=3;
        $pages->applyLimit($criteria);

        $review = Reviews::model()->findAll($criteria);
        $i=1;
        foreach($review as $review)
        {
           $rate=$review['rating'];
           $this->widget('CStarRating',array(
                'name'=>'rating'.$i,
                'minRating'=>1,
                'maxRating'=>5,
                'starCount'=>5,
                'value'=>$rate,
                'readOnly'=>true,
            ));
            echo "<br/>";
            echo $review['title'];
            echo "<br/>";
            echo "<font color='brown'>".ucfirst($review['name'])."</font><br/>";
            echo $review['body'];
            echo "<br/>";
            echo "Posted on : ".$review['time'];
            echo "<hr/><br/>";
            $i++;
        }
$this->widget('CLinkPager', array(
    'pages' => $pages,
)) ?>
```

I am getting evering thing ok but I am not getting Stars (*) in my review form, instead I am getting radio buttons ? how can i get them back , thanks

Comment: what javascript is it generating?

Comment: Check your browser's console for javascript errors. If that doesn't help you fix it, post the errors here. This has happened to me a couple of times and both times it was because of a javascript error on the page.

Comment: I have checked, i am getting no error in firebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem while developing an application with Yii. The radio buttons change to stars if appropriate CSS file is loaded. So check html ids, spans and see if you have corresponding field in your CSS files. You also need to have images of stars(background,foreground) on your server. 
I solved it by manually download the original jquery patch, and used it's included CSS file and images.